# como filtrar campos con varios and y con or en mysql?

Tags: mysql

Mi query es el siguiente

```
select * from paciente pc 
join persona per on per.dni=pc.dni
join det_pac_tra dp on dp.dni=pc.dni 
where  pc.cod_centro_salud='3'  and pc.cod_situacion='1' and dp.frecuencia_fase1 = '1' or  dp.frecuencia_fase2='2'
```

les explico tengo que traer a todos los pacientes que tengan el `cod_centro=3` y que sus  `dp.frecuencia_fase1 = '1'` o `dp.frecuencia_fase2='2'` pero al ejecutar mi query me sale todos lo pacientes de todos los `cod_centro` que esta mal

Comment: creo que tu respuesta se resuelve con parentesis

Comment: Prueba poner esto `dp.frecuencia_fase1 = '1' or  dp.frecuencia_fase2='2'` entre paréntesis

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es cómo estás usando las condiciones `AND` y `OR`. La precedencia indica que primero se evalúan los `AND` y el `OR` al final, voy a reescribirlo con paréntesis para que te quede claro por qué estás obteniendo esos resultados:

```
select * 
from paciente pc 
inner join persona per 
    on per.dni=pc.dni
inner join det_pac_tra dp 
    on dp.dni=pc.dni 
where ( pc.cod_centro_salud='3' 
        and pc.cod_situacion='1' 
        and dp.frecuencia_fase1 = '1')
or dp.frecuencia_fase2='2';
```

En este caso, si `dp.frecuencia_fase2='2'` es verdadero, entonces todo el `WHERE` es verdadero.

Puedes reescribirlo de la siguiente forma:

```
select * 
from paciente pc 
inner join persona per 
    on per.dni=pc.dni
inner join det_pac_tra dp 
    on dp.dni=pc.dni 
where pc.cod_centro_salud='3' 
and pc.cod_situacion='1' 
and (dp.frecuencia_fase1 = '1'
     or dp.frecuencia_fase2='2');
```

O lo que es más sencillo sería usar `IN`:

```
select * 
from paciente pc 
inner join persona per 
    on per.dni=pc.dni
inner join det_pac_tra dp 
    on dp.dni=pc.dni 
where pc.cod_centro_salud='3' 
and pc.cod_situacion='1' 
and dp.frecuencia_fase1 in ('1','2');
```

Comment: Estaba por escribir algo similar.. para referencia (y se va a caer cuando cambie la version) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html

Comment: @gbianchi que version va a salir deprecada?

Comment: no no, lo digo pq el link apunta a una version particular del help.. @JackNavaRow